# How to split an array using strings?

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

I need to write a program that prompts the user to input a string, then determine the middle of the string, and generate a new string which swaps the two halves of the string and then output the results.

So far I have

```
int main(void) {

char *string = NULL;
char temp[1000];
cout << "Please enter a string" << endl;
cin.getline(temp, 999);
int length = strlen(temp);
string = new char[length];
strcpy(string,temp);
length = length / 2;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which takes in the string and stores it. I just need a way to move that second half to a new array and I know I need to use strcpy() but I don't know how to properly reference that portion of the array.

Comment: Take a look at [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy). However, you should try to use `std::string` instead and standard algorithms.

Comment: is there a way to get strncpy to start taking the array after n? or will it only do before n?

Comment: Before you start figuring out the algorithm, you might want to fix the obvious bug in the shown code that will lead to undefined behavior, memory corruption, and random crashes (hint: strlen() doesn't count the trailing '\0' that strcpy() adds).

Comment: Think about what an array is. It decays to a pointer, so you can increment the pointer to point to the middle of the array.

Comment: @Tremors You can use `&string[n]` to start copying from `n`.

Comment: @Barmar by this do you mean do it as strncpy(&string[n], temp, length); ?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: I got it, needed to be on the temp variable though not string! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++ I'm going to suggest a standard library algorithm. You're asking to swap two halves of a sequence and [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) does just that. Unfortunately it does the rotation in-place and you want the result in a different string.

You could copy the string and then do the rotation but there is a [`std::rotate_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate_copy) algorithm that will do both (and faster than separate copy/rotate steps).

Example with `char` arrays:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char text[1000], result[1000];
    std::cout << "Please enter a string\n";
    std::cin.getline(text, 999);
    size_t length = strlen(text);

    std::rotate_copy(text, text + length / 2, text + length, result);
    result[length] = '\0';

    std::cout << text << '\n' << result << '\n';
}
```

Example with `std::string`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string text, result;
    std::cout << "Please enter a string\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    size_t length = text.size();

    result.resize(length);
    std::rotate_copy(text.begin(), text.begin() + length / 2, text.end(), result.begin());

    std::cout << text << '\n' << result << '\n';
}
```

[Demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Dvfrcj)

You could possibly use [`std::swap_ranges`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap_ranges) but that assumes both ranges are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to use C, use strncpy. However, I recommend using C++ `std::string` and using the `std::string.substr()` and concatenation. The latter would be easier at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

You were half way through the solution. Here I finished it using strncpy to get the first half and pointer incrementation to get the second one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char temp[1000];
    cout << "Please enter a string" << endl;
    cin.getline(temp, 999);
    int length = strlen(temp);

    char firstHalf[512];
    strncpy (firstHalf, temp, length/2);
    cout << "firstHalf: " << firstHalf << endl;

    char* secondHalf = temp + length/2; 
    cout << "secondHalf: " << secondHalf << endl;

    char* swapped_str = strcat(secondHalf, firstHalf);  
    cout << "Swapped string: " << swapped_str << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This is more of a c style answer (using <cstring>) than a cpp one. I agree with @jalomas7 and would personally use <string> to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string text(whatever...);
int sz = text.size() / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    std::swap(text[i], text[sz + i]);
```

This might be off by one when `text.size()` is odd.